From where does this equation of quadrupole potential of a quadrupole mass filter derive from?
Quoting from thesis "Chip-scale quadrupole mass filters
for a Micro-Gas Analyzer" (page 23):



As I am solving quadrupole mass filter equation, I am stuck from where quadrupole potential equation comes from as everywhere it is written but i did not find its solution.

I cropped the screenshot and added credit to original thesis.

The electric potential $\Phi(x,y)$ must satisfy

the boundary condition at the surface of the positive electrodes
$$\Phi(x,y)=+\Phi_0/2 \quad\text{ where } x^2-y^2=+r_0^2,$$
the boundary condition at the surface of the negative electrodes
$$\Phi(x,y)=-\Phi_0/2 \quad\text{ where } x^2-y^2=-r_0^2,$$
and Laplace's equation everywhere between the electrodes
$$\frac{\partial^2\Phi(x,y)}{\partial x^2}
  +\frac{\partial^2\Phi(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0.$$

All this together leads to the unique solution
$$\Phi(x,y)=\frac{\Phi_0(x^2-y^2)}{2r_0^2}$$
